# How to store and extract SIFT features from external file

Tags: python, image-processing, sift, keypoint

I'm working on Content based Search Engine in python. I'm able to extract keypoints but My dataset contains 9k images I've to store features so I can directly compare those afterwards. Please suggest me storing and extracting method.

Comment: Please add some code - an example of how did you extract keypoints? how does they look like... a simple print of an example.

Comment: following is the code for storing them. You'll get idea of structure from code.                      
 **bold**for point in kp:
    temp = (point.pt, point.size, point.angle, point.response, point.octave,
        point.class_id)
    index.append(temp).....**bold**..... after this I dump index in .txt file. This much works properly. I need extraction method for this. Extraction from .txt file